# Java & Apache-poi open workbook throws exception

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Here is my testcase:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestWB {

File sourceA;
File sourceB;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    sourceA = new File("C:\\junit\\sourceA.xls");
    sourceB = new File("C:\\junit\\sourceB.xls");
}

@Test
public final void testValid() {
    try {
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(sourceA);
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public final void testInValid() {
    try {
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(sourceB);
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Where sourceA.xls passes and is loaded, SourceB.xls is troubeling. Here is the exception code:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected record type (org.apache.poi.hssf.record.StringRecord)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.RowRecordsAggregate.<init>(RowRecordsAggregate.java:97)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.<init>(InternalSheet.java:172)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalSheet.createSheet(InternalSheet.java:127)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:291)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:88)
    at TestWB.testInValid(TestWB.java:35)
    ...
```

If I open the xls - change nothing as far as I know - save it. it works as it should.
How can I fix this issue without manual actions from the user (open - save - close)

thank you

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And where did the problematic Excel file come from?

Comment: I'm using apache poi 3.9, the file is generated from an external source (no access to code or process)

Comment: Does 3.10 beta 2 fix it?

Comment: Nope, 3.10-beta-2 doesn't help, i've tried 3.8, 3.9, 3.10-beta1

Comment: So if you only load SourceB (i.e. without SourceA) it's working? Can you provide your test-XLSs?

Comment: no its not, but if i open source b, and save it, its working. also i've observed that when saved, the sice shrink from about 91KB to 51 Kb. I i'm sorry but can't provide the xls.

Comment: 3.12 neither works out this exception